# Derive return type from template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like to represent a fixed point number using P total number of bits and F number of fractional bits (leaving P-F-1 integer bits, one bit reserved as sign bit) :

```
#include <bitset>

// Fixed point class
// P : Total number of bits
// F : Number of fractional bits
namespace FPUtils {
  template <unsigned P, unsigned F> class MyFPClass {
  public:
         MyFPClass(std::string b="") : m_bits(b) { value = m_bits.to_ulong(); }
  private:
         unsigned int value;
         std::bitset<P> m_bits;
  };
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to add two MyFPClass objects with different number of template arguments, and use the highest possible resolution in the result. The only solution I found is :

```
template<unsigned X, unsigned Y, unsigned X1, unsigned Y1, 
         unsigned X2, unsigned Y2> MyFPClass<X,Y> 
add(const MyFPClass<X1,Y1>& a, const MyFPClass<X2,Y2>& b){
    std::cout << "In add" << std::endl;
}
```

Which I can use like this :

```
int main(){
    MyFPClass<9,7> a("101000110"); // has 1 integer bit
    MyFPClass<10,6> b("0111000110"); // has 3 integer bits
    MyFPClass<11,7> c; // has 3 integer bits, 7 fractional bits, 1 sign bit
    c = FPUtils::add<11,7,9,7,10,6>(a,b);

    // How can I derive the input type directly from the input parameter, so that I can do e.g. :
    // MyFPClass<9,7> c(a + b);
    // or 
    //MyFPClass<9,7> c = a + b;
}
```

How can I define a e.g. function `operator+(const MyFPClass<P1,F1>& a, const MyFPClass<P2,F2>& b)` where P1,F1,P2,F2 are derived from the input parameters a and b?

Comment: What is the formula for the output's `P` and `F` based on the inputs' `P`s and `F`s?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? The question is much clearer and much more coherent than most first questions.

Comment: fix `l1a` and `l1b`. also `l1d` vs `c`, and don't mix in `operator+` into the question, it's really not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++14, `std::max` is constexpr, so you can do:

```
template<unsigned X1, unsigned Y1, unsigned X2, unsigned Y2>
L1TopoDataTypes<std::max(Y1, Y2) + std::max(X1 - Y1, X2 - Y2), std::max(Y1, Y2)> 
add(const L1TopoDataTypes<X1,Y1>& a, const L1TopoDataTypes<X2,Y2>& b){
    std::cout << "In add" << std::endl;
}
```

before, you may use ternary operator:

```
template<unsigned X1, unsigned Y1, unsigned X2, unsigned Y2>
L1TopoDataTypes<(Y1 < Y2 ? Y2 : Y1) + ((X1 - Y1 < X2 - Y2) ? X1 - Y1 : X2 - Y2),
                (Y1 < Y2 ? Y2 : Y1)> 
add(const L1TopoDataTypes<X1, Y1>& a, const L1TopoDataTypes<X2, Y2>& b){
    std::cout << "In add" << std::endl;
}
```